# Parcelas - Sistema Financeiro PHP

Tags: php, mariadb

Estou a fazer um sistema financeiro, mas por insegurança e desconhecimento do assunto, estou com a seguinte dúvida...

Vamos supor que: Temos um valor de R$ 1299,99 ou similar.

Qual seria a forma ideal de dividir as parcelas para registrar em um BD?

12 parcelas de R$ 1299,99? (Daria R$ 108,3325)

> Gostaria de armazenar apenas 2 dígitos após a virgula.

SEGUINDO A LÓGICA DO BANCO DE DADOS:

```
CREATE TABLE TRANSACAO (
codigo INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (codigo)
);

CREATE TABLE TRANSACAO_PARCELA (
codigo INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
valor DOUBLE(11,2) NOT NULL,
cod_transacao INT,
FOREIGN KEY(cod_transacao),
PRIMARY KEY (codigo)
);
```

> Gostaria de sugestões ou de exemplos de como posso fazer esse procedimento.

Comment: Em nosso sistema financeiro trabalhamos da seguinte forma: 
Ao dividir um valor como mencionado. Nós utilizamos arredondar para baixo e na última parcela acrescentamos o valor que ficou faltando para chegar até o total.
Outra situação é nós sempre utilizamos o prazo sempre com o valor de 30 dias. O que faz com que a data de vencimento fique menor em alguns meses pelo fato de alguns meses terem 31 ou 28 dias. No seu exemplo acima, utilizamos a seguinte situação: 11 parcelas no valor de R$ 108,33 e a 12ª parcela no valor de R$ 108,36.